# How to search External Id field values in different objects in salesforce

Tags: visualforce, community

For example I have Account ,Contact and Opportunity in this three objects i have external Id values

when i am trying to search with External Id value if this value matching with any object then i have to display those records.

Comment: Is doing 3 SOQL queries not an option?

Comment: Can you use SOSL?